# display calendar when i hover the mouse in text box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, calendar

I've been looking around for some time now and can't seem to find anything for what I'd like. I want it to be that when you hover over a text box named the month, my PHP calendar will appear. And then provides a manipulation on that calendar. I'm just a beginner and a student who doesn't have enough knowledge to program a system using javascript and jQuery so I suggest you to use PHP language :)
`

```
//to read the date today
$currentMonth = date ("m");



//timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');


//Today
$today = date ('Y-m-d',time());

// For H3 Title
$html_title = date('m / Y', $timestamp);


//create prev & next month link  (hour,min,sec,mon,day,day,year


$prev = date('Y-m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp)-1, 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));
$next = date('Y-m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp)+1, 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));    




//Number Of days in the month
$day_count = date('t' , $timestamp);


//0:Sun 1:Mon 2:tue
$str = date('w' , mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp), 1,date('Y',$timestamp)));


//create calendar
$weeks = array();
$week = '';


//add empty cellpadding
$week .= str_repeat('<td></td>', $str);
for ( $day = 1; $day <=$day_count; $day++, $str++) {

$date = $ym.'-'.$day;

if ($today == $date) {
    $week .= '<td class="today">'.$day;
    }
    else{
        $week .= '<td>'. $day;
        }
    $week .= '</td>';

    //end of the week or of the moth
    if ($str % 7 == 6 || $day == $day_count) {

        if($day == $day_count) {
        //add empty cell
        $week .= str_repeat ('<td></td>' , 6 - ($str % 7));
        }

        $weeks[] = '<tr>'.$week.'</tr>';

        //prepare for new week
        $week = '';

}

}





?>
<!DOCTYPE.html>
<html.lang"ja">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div id="c2">
<h3><div class="title"><a href="?ym=<?php echo $prev; ?>">&lt;</a><?php echo $html_title; ?><a href="?ym=<?php echo $next; ?>">&gt;  </a></div></h3>
<br>
<table class="table table-bordered" id = "calendar" >
    <tr>
    <th>Sun</th>
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thur</th>
    <th>Fri</th>
    <th>Sat</th>
    </tr>
    <center>
    <?php
    foreach ($weeks as $week) {
            echo $week;
        }
        ?>  
    </center>

</table>
</div>

<div id="booking">
        <center>
        <h1>This is your month</h1>
        <input  id="result" type="text" name="month" value="<?php echo $month ?>" readonly>
        <br>
        <h1>Check In </h1>
        <Input type="number" min="<?php echo $day_today; ?>" max="<?php echo $day_count; ?>" value = "<?php echo $day_today; ?>">
        <br>
        <h1>Adults</h1>
        <input type="number" name="adult" min="1" max="10">
        <br>
        <h1>Kids</h1>
        <input type="number" name="kid" min="1" max="10">
        <br>
        </center>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this  [example](https://codepen.io/hansfranz/pen/bRmVQY) JS is triggered with the Keyword `focus` like:

```
`$("#result").focus(function() {
  $(".calendar").addClass("someCss")
});`
```

and adds and removes a CSS class when the user clicks into the field or leaves it. You can do the same thing with `$("#result").on("mouseenter", function()` the `mouseenter` in JS like `hover` in CSS. To make the calendar disappear you would use `mouseleave`.

When you really want to do it with hover I would suggest to use bootstraps [popover](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/) function. and display your calendar inside the popover. Hope that helps

Comment: I think your suggestion is great but is it easier to put the calendar inside the popover than making the hovering?

Comment: What you want to use is really your thing. The thing with the popovers is that they look more professional. Of course you can do it yourself with the code snippet I showed you. Add some Background to the calendar and so on and it will look good as well. You have to decide what works best for you. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do it on php.but you can possibly use javascript. put a onhover attribute on your textbox month and do something on that event

Comment: @shimo Not that i care for the points but are you kidding? Why do you select that answer?

Comment: bcause he is my master in real life hahaha

Comment: ohhhh no!!! i got it........ sorry but i accidentally clicked the check sign and i dont know what does it mean... but now i know haha

Comment: btw! I used to put your suggestion on my codes and its really great